# TextToSpeech on Android 11

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Up to API 29 tts is working fine on android to speak out any text

But on API 30 tts is not working anymore and i do not know why

The google documentation says :

"Apps targeting Android 11 that use text-to-speech should declare TextToSpeech.Engine#INTENT_ACTION_TTS_SERVICE in the elements of their manifest"

I do not exactly know what they mean and how to implement this in the manifest.

I hope anybody can help me with this.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Although probably not the best answer (or maybe just a glitch on Androids part) add the following code just above the `<application` in your manifest.

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TTS_SERVICE" />
    </intent>
</queries>

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
```

After adding this code my TTS service started to work again, but I do get a warning from the manifest file about it not being allowed there, but anywhere in the manifest gives this same warning so I suppress it with `<!--suppress AndroidElementNotAllowed -->` just above the `<manifest` tag at the top.

Comment: He Jayce thank you so far for your solution. I will check this out. Hopefully we will get a better solution soon . The Google documentation is really poor without any explanation

Comment: Wow this worked but I'm more surprised that this problem exists!  very wierd.

Answer (score 4):

[@jayce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63514931/13512903)'s answer helps if app is targeting the Android 11
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech

Note: sorry for the noise but I don't have enough reputation to put my comment there.